# How can I install Die Hard Movie Theme?

Tags: themes

In **Live Free or Die Hard movie**, in the initial scene, Matthew Farrell operated on his computer, and the desktop appearance had a hacker style. The theme, command line, icons are awesome. Can anyone please help me to install this theme on my Ubuntu 16.04?

[image: screen grab]

Comment: There is no such theme. It's a fake interface made specifically for the movie, as they often are.

Comment: @dobey lol nice. anyway, that does look like a fake interface like you said. To OP: it is easy to make the terminal look "hackerish" by Hollywood standards if you just set the terminal background semi-transparent and the terminal text to green in color.

Comment: The WM theme could probably be done, and maybe a theme for conky to look similar. The chat looks totally fake, so probably not really doable. I can't even tell what the icons are, but several look like pretty standard icons, from multiple different themes.

Comment: The theme is on gnome look https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Die+Hard+4.0+GTK+theme?content=84355 . There are several https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Die+Hard+4.0+-+Matthew+Farrel's+theme+(E?content=66714 and https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1002801/ . The themes are quite old, written for gtk2 and emerald , sort of depends on what version of Ubuntu you are using and if you have compiz. The extreme left of the screen is conky , not sure of the conky theme.

Answer (score 2):

The theme is old and written for compiz (emerald) - [about emerald](http://wiki.compiz.org/Decorators/Emerald)

There are several options on gnome look:

[Die Hard first option](https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Die+Hard+4.0+GTK+theme?content=84355)

[image]

[Die Hard second option](https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Die+Hard+4.0+-+Matthew+Farrel's+theme+(E?content=66714)

[image]

[Die Hard third option](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1002801/)

[image]

The information on the left of the screenshots is conky. Not sure of the theme.

It may be here - https://kitty-o-connor.deviantart.com/art/Die-Hard-4-Conky-539632171

[image]

Obviously not a perfect match, but you could start with that template and modify it to your desire.

As the themes are old there is no guarantee they will work. Install compiz and put the themes in ~/.themes and give it a try.

If you want them for gnome-shell you would have to modify or write a custom them, but perhaps you can use the old themes as a general template for colors / fonts ?

There are similar named themes on kde look and xfce look as well (again all for emerald). You may have the best luck with xfce + compiz as xfce has changed less than gnome or kde since the theme was written.

[kde look](https://store.kde.org/content/show.php/Die+Hard+4.0+-+Matthew+Farrel%27s+theme+(E?content=66714)

[xfce look](https://www.xfce-look.org/content/show.php?content=84355)